# How to add 'favorite' button in ios app

Tags: ios7

I am new to ios dev and in middle of app. I need to add button in my app which pops up two cells 1) Add to favorites 2) Show favorites.

The content needs to be added is simple string and same for show favorites.

I searched few answers but could not easily grasp.
Can someone explain the approach I should take?

Comment: read the apple documentary to begin with. Second off, make sure you know what you're trying to do. I am honestly confused in what you're asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need data serialization, and/or persistance.

Small amount of data = Data Persistence.

Large = Serialization, aka Archiving. All arrays can do it, find some wenderlich tutorials.

(I can't seem to find any basic tutorials on his site or I'd link one here, all of it is kinda advanced database stuff)...

These keywords should be enough to get you going on yahoo or www.DUckDuckGo.com (doesn't personalize results, I try to get "pure" results when searching myself)